# Wrong line numbers with multiline grep -P [ Perl extension ] match

Tags: perl, sed, awk, grep, pcre

I have been using  `grep` with `perl` extension for multiline match .However it turns out that the line number of all the match depends on the number of lines in the first multiline match  !

The `grep` regex  to find the `c` function start :

```
   grep -iPn '^[^\S\n]*?\w+\s+\w+?\s*\([\w-0-9,/* \s]*\)\s*\{$'
```

I can explain better with an example :

Suppose these two function exists in the source file

```
      int f1(int a) {       

      int 
      f2 (int b )        
      {
```

In this case ,the grep matches the regex successfully and the line number output to stdout is in par with the line number of the source file .

The problem arises when a multiline function comes first .This alters the line number output and after examining the file for some time I came to a conclusion. The multiline functions are matched but read as a single line by the grep therefore it assigns the whole function a single line number.The next line that follows the function gets its line number short depending on the number of lines the 'function definition start regex 'occupies.

There are numerous multiline `C` functions in my file and the line number is way too deviated for each one of them.

Is there a way to correct this ?

Comment: Is a solution that reads an entire file into memory before matching against it acceptable? In other words, are your input files not huge? I assume that C source files will be reasonably sized. If we can do it this way then it becomes easier.

Comment: Yes , reasonably sized but there is always a limit .As you have mentioned 'This way ' but which ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the pcregrep for the same regex shows the correct line number !

```
 pcregrep -Mni '^[^\S\n]*?\w+\s+\w+?\s*\([\w-0-9,/* \s]*\)\s*\{$'
```

Answer (score 0):

Your solution doesn't work with my (linux, gnu)grep.

I need to add `-z` to make it work. With -z "lines" are separated by a null char; this way you have a single "line", so line numbers wont work :( but byte offset do. Sometimes that is enough...

So, using grep:

```
grep -ziPbo '^[^\S\n]*?\w+\s+\w+?\s*\([\w-0-9,/* \s]*\)\s*\{$'
```

obtaining

```
24:int 
f2 (int b )        
{
```